# Find all components by name using wildcard

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to find all Ember components based on their name using a wildcard or regex?

so far I found a way to find a component by its fullName: 

`appInstance.lookup('component:my-component')`

but what I want to achieve is to do something like:

`appInstance.lookup('component:my-*')`

which will return an array of components whose name begins with 'my-'

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list the names of all entries by using `require.entries`:

```
function getKeys(){
  return Object.keys(require.entries).filter(function(key){
    return /.*components\/my-.*/.test(key);
};
```

Then you can make a `lookup` with this keys. *(Be aware that function `getKeys` returns both component's js file names and template file names.)*